# What are the missing letters?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

What letters are missing from the end of this list?

```
AC     DI     IM     NI     TM
AG     DM     IR     NM     TU
AI     DN     IW     NT     TV
AL     DS     JN     OC     VN
AM     ED     KA     OM     VW
AP     EM     KO     RA     XT
AV     EN     LA     RO     YK
AW     HN     LF     SK     YN
CN     HO     LI     SM     YW
CS     IH     MN     TC     ??
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The letters are the abbreviations of the 50 states backwards, and the last should be "ZA" for Arizona

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!   Nice Answer!